# how to find eye level in complex pictures?

Tags: drawing, painting

I know we can continue the lines and when all converge together that place is a vanishing point and along that horizontal line is eye level.
But what about complex pictures and paintings in which even you can't see the line between sky and ground or when there are no guidelines like a house or a piece of wood or anything to help you continue that line and then find the converge point?

I don't know if I send what I mean or no -  mean in some pictures it's so difficult, please tell me the way for those.

- I can't find a good image about what I mean but for example mostly I can't find eye level and vp in vintage paintings mostly when there is no guidelines like a house like a piece of wood or anything or you cant see the line between sky and ground.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am so mad and sad and hopeless now :( I just start drawing I know if I find this eye-level easy then I can draw the picture more easily, but I can't find it! I've searched a lot but all I found was about simple pictures with many lines in it that can help you to find it easy - but I am looking for difficult pictures and how to find the eye lever of them.

Comment: Be aware that when looking at works by The Masters... one of the reasons they are referred to as "masters" is that they inherently percieved things like perspective. Many didn't *actually* plot and adhere to any style of grid. They merely painted. It was *far more* about the ability to perceive these things and convey them as opposed to using any mathematically defined grids. In fact, one can **often** try to apply a perspective grid to a work from a Master and see that any grid isn't really reflected. It was later that humans created defined grids and more mathematical plots, i.e. Escher.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the images do actually have a horizon you can use to *estimate* the eye level:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the perspective in paintings aren't always completely geometrically well defined. There can be some "eye-balling" involved.

If there is no visible horizon you can have a look at where in the image you can see the top and bottom of objects.

As example, here is the last image with the bottoms colored in yellow and the tops in blue. The eye level must be somewhere between the lowest bottom and the highest top you can see.

[image]

(The two last examples by Bruegel looks a bit like [parallel projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection), so perhaps they can't be said to have an eye level.)

Comment: how you found those eye levels? and can you tell me the way i can use for complex pictures as i said in my first question that there is no guidelines and no visible sky and ground touch. and my last question is  can you find any vanishing point on top images  ? for example i want to add a box to each of those images how to find vanishing point for complex pictures ? . thank you

Comment: @Dude in the first picture if you look carefully the horizon is visible. Anyway you look at the objects objects "bow" upward above the horizon and below they "bow" downwards.

Comment: As @joojaa said, the horizon is visible. I deliberately made a thick red line because I can't tell for sure *exactly* where the artist wanted the eye level to be. It's a qualified guess. But for example in the second image, you can see some sky and some green field. It's a bit foggy (and pixelated) but the horizon must be somewhere in between.

Comment: I don't think I can give you one method that will work for all complex images. Some images just contain too little information. About vanishing points. An image can have several vanishing points or none. Only objects with parallel lines share the same vanishing point. Have a look at some of the [questions about vanishing points](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=vanishing+point). For example [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/116025/84899).

Comment: It might be worth noting that there does not exist a wanishing point in a image there exists many many wanishing points

Comment: thank you so much - but is there any chance you give me the advice for the rest of question actually my point is not about simple images and maybe i chosed some wrong refrences but as i explaned im looking for finding eye level in some of pictures and paintings that you cannot see and maybe you dont have even an edge between sky and ground and maybe its indoor ! and also you dont have any guidlines to countinue them and find the converging point. i mean is realy complex images

Comment: like imagine i cover the doors in this image and you can't see the sky and  ground touch point any more and there is no guidelines i mean some thing like it. i don't know if it's a good reference but i try to send you whats i mean   https://s16.picofile.com/file/8415687334/wewew.jpg

Comment: There can be images where it's impossible to determine the perspective accurately (or at least *I* don't know how). In the latest example, you can do as @joojaa suggested and look at where you can see the top and bottom of objects. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjAOf.png) I've tried to color the bottoms in yellow and the tops in blue. The eye level must be in between somewhere.

Comment: Add that to answer.

Comment: wow guys you'r helps were really help full ! thank you but i have a question about this image . if the eye level is the one i wrote in image why the red lines goes to the eye level but the white and blue ones they going some where else up !   https://s16.picofile.com/file/8415777300/sssss.jpg   clean image :  https://s17.picofile.com/file/8415777650/evening_by_darnok9_ddw3s6j_fullview.jpg

Comment: This looks like a photo collage with digital painting on top. The different parts of the image seems to come from different images, so the perspective doesn't make geometrically sense. It's way off actually. You'll never find the correct lines. Besides that, if it was a perfect perspective, the blue and white lines would meet the eye level in a *second* vanishing point. When you see the corner of a box/building like this, it's a [two-point perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#/media/File:Perspective1.jpg).

Comment: so is it means the artist didn't did a well job to matching perspective ? or it can be a style ?

Comment: It can definitely be a style. There aren't really "rules" to art is there? If it works it works. An image can show things that aren't possible in real life. That's one of the reasons people still paint and draw even though most people carry around cameras. In this particular image I think the crazy perspective gives the image some of the chaos and randomness a big city can have. Helps convey the *feeling* you might get walking the streets rather than how it actually *looks*.

Comment: wow . nice ! thank's ... so i just have to practice my eyes  for example if i want put (paint) something inside this image or this kind of images or even in correct perspective images ? true ? so do you have any suggestion or video or course that you think i have to watch for this purpose ?

Comment: If an image has a perfect perspective it's probably best to follow that. In other images you probably have to just use you artistic sense. Hard to mix those two styles. There are *tons* of tutorials online. Don't really know what to recommend. Guess you have to browse and see if you can find something that suits you. I'm not really an expert or anything. But years ago I studied architecture and where taught how to draw perspective from elevations like [this](https://www.joshuanava.biz/fundamentals/images/1863_15_45-drop-plan-perspective-drawing.jpg). That was quite an eye-opener.

Comment: thank you so much you helped alot :)

Comment: is it true that in one picture we can have difrent (for example 2 point perspective vanishing point places )? i did it for test but for example if you put your two vp points too close to each other you will get some diffrent shape of cube for example - and if you put them a little far another diffrent shape and if you put them so far so another diffrent shape ! so it is look like you changing the lens of camera in one picture !!! so in my mind in one specific token picture all the vanishing points are in a same possition because otherwise you will see some shapes completly diffrent !

Comment: a picture for my last question to send what i mean better : https://s16.picofile.com/file/8416020092/diff.jpg

Comment: You can't just place additional vanishing points where you want. I *think* the distance between the two new points must be the same as the original two. But you should really ask this as a new question (*after* searching the site for a similar question). We can't keep adding to this one. 

Comment: ok thank you so much my friend