# How many vanishing point does 2 point perspective can have

Tags: perspective

I'm trying to learn perspective from a book and it says that 1 point perspective can only have 1 vanishing point, so I'm assuming that 2 points can have more than 2 vanishing points.

Comment: Can you walk through your logic of how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: I was reading a book and it said that you can have an infinite amount of vanishing points, but the only exception is the one-point perspective it can only have one vanishing point. That's why I was wondering if 2 points can have more than 2 vanishing points.

Comment: well actually there is just perspective and 1 point, 2 point and 3 point are just special cases. if your scene consists of anything other than colinear cubes then you will in fact have infinite wanishing points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

If 1 point perspective has one vanishing point.

Don't you think it is logical to assume that 2 point perspective has 2 vanishing points? So, in this case, no. The point of a two-point perspective is to have 2 vanishing points so you can focus on learning 2 point perspective. (The other axis will be parallel)

A 3 point perspective has 3 vanishing points.

**Part 2**

The concept of a 1 or 2 or 3 point perspective is to facilitate our understanding of a more or less constructed world. Architecture, furniture, city blocks. It is a  simplification of a world constructed around orthogonal axis. You align a rectangular table to be parallel to a wall with a ceiling parallel to the floor with walls at 90° of the other walls.

But in reality, every single line has it own vanishing point. It turns out that if another line is parallel to this line, they share the same vanishing point (VP), except when it does not share it anymore. When you turn a table, now they do not share the same VP as the walls, so you now have new VP for each group of lines of the table.

Take a look at some related questions.

[Finding the possible vanishing points in a landscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116025/finding-the-possible-vanishing-points-in-a-landscape/116027#116027)

[At what point does 1 point perspective become 2 point perspective?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117014/at-what-point-does-1-point-perspective-become-2-point-perspective/117026#117026)